# How to change one character of an std::string?

Tags: c++, string

When I try to make this affect operation:

```
unsigned char castME[65536];
// castMe = "dqslqdqslmd";
std::string str = (char*)castMe;
str[str.find_first_of("Ì")] = '\0';
```

I get the blow exception on the 1691 th (`return (this->_Myptr()[_Off]);`) line of the `xstring` file.

> Project.exe has triggered a breakpoint

Can someone explain me what's wrong and how to fix it, please ?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Two things: What if the character you search for can't be found? Secondly, that's not how you terminate a `std::string`, use [`std::string::substr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) instead (but remember my first point!)

Comment: `= (char*)castMe` ... why cast?

Comment: well, `'\0'` should be also placed at the end of the array if you're constructing like this.

Comment: Just use `std::vector<unsigned char> data` for binary data. This is not what `std::string` has been made for.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, Deleting that 3th line, triggers this exception `An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException' occurred in Project.exe Additional information: External component has thrown an exception.` on the 2296 th line of `xstring`.

Comment: @Bartek Banachewicz is right: If the array coincidentally does not contain a zero byte, the string construction may run into trouble already because it doesn't know how much memory is valid behind the char pointer its ctor has been passed; it's looking for the terminating zero which never comes.

Comment: Also `find_first_of` will return `npos` if it fails. Indexing by that is pretty much always guaranteed to fail (UB) if the string doesn't contain the character you're looking for.

Comment: @PeterSchneider: NUL termination is important before the character buffer is passed to the constructor, but it's being performed within the `std::string` *after* construction... it's attempting to overwrite internally (clearly presumes a `find_first_of` match), probably thinking that will do the equivalent of an `erase` from that position in the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of the call

```
str.find_first_of("Ì")
```

can be `std::string::npos` (that is neither symbol can be found).

So you should write something as

```
std::string::size_type n = str.find_first_of("Ì");

if ( n != std::string::npos ) str[n] = '\0';
```

Or maybe you wanted the following

```
std::string::size_type n = str.find_first_of("Ì");

if ( n != std::string::npos ) str.erase( n );
```

Comment: `str[n] = '\0';` - well, maybe and maybe not.  that writes a NUL into the `string`, but the `string` continues to contain all the prior content with that single character overwritten - it is not newly terminated at the NUL.  `.size()` is unchanged, and iteration will continue past the NUL.  Any attempt to write out the string will still send characters including and after the NUL.  It's more likely that an `.erase(n);` is intended.